# Maximum number of concurrent users connected to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a limit to the maximum number of concurrent users connected to SQL Server 2008? I am guessing computer resources determine that limit (if it exists), but I am also wondering if there is a theoretical limit. I have tried googling the answer, but all the information I have found is based upon earlier versions of SQL Server. If there is a limit, does it apply to just a database or a SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

User connections: 32767