# SQL Connections Max from .NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, connection-pooling

Using .NET running in an Azure cloud service, with a process with many SQL Server connection strings (SQL authentication, not Windows), what is the maximum number of connections that can be made to different databases?

I am putting together a system that needs to read/write to many MSSQL instances on different hosts at the same time and am looking to gather information/documentation on limits. This is not the same as multiple connections going to the same database, this is for example 40 strings (therefore 40 connection pools) to 40 different databases under different security contexts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

User connections: 32767

You see also
 [Maximum number of concurrent users connected to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055216/maximum-number-of-concurrent-users-connected-to-sql-server-2008)

For you question (num max connections pools), I view the [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionPoolGroup.cs)  of ADO.NET and I found that the pools are stored ( _poolCollection) in a ConcurrentDictionary then 
the number max of pool is the the number max of entry in the dictionary.  In the documentation says

> For very large ConcurrentDictionary objects, you can increase the maximum array size to 2 gigabytes (GB) on a 64-bit system by setting the  configuration element to true in the run-time environment.

I think that there aren't real limits, depends on the machine

Comment: Read carefully the second part of the question